# Word to qualify a group of people in between a Junior and a Senior (not school or work related)

Tags: word-request

I would like to know what is the word/term for those people that are currently between their 35s and 60s, they are not senior nor junior, what are they? Medior?

I am not speaking about work related level, just life related level I guess? Do you know if there is any term for that? Couldn't find my way out on Google.

Comment: *in the prime of life*? *working-aged adults*? *working stiffs*? *parents*? *marrieds*? *home-owners*? Are you thinking of a particular life event that you assume they've all done at 35 but which may become undone/superseded later? Or is this just an arbitrary classification?

Answer (score 3):

***Middle-aged***:

> Middle age is the *period of age beyond young adulthood but before the onset of old age*. Though the exact range is disputed, most sources place middle adulthood between the ages of 45-65. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_age))

I think outside a professional context, the term ***middle-aged*** can be used. I know you said over 35, but that can be relative. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/middle-aged) says

> If you describe someone as ***middle-aged***, you mean that they are neither young nor old. People ***between the ages of 40 and 60*** are usually considered to be middle-aged.

Now, we could add that ***junior*** and ***senior*** are relative too. If you are 5 years older than me that makes you my senior and me your junior in certain aspects of life :-)

Consider

> ***be 10/20, etc years sb's junior*** - to be 10, 20, etc years younger than someone:
>
> - My wife is 8 years my ***junior***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/junior))

That age groups are not a fixed is not surprising in our rapidly progressing world. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth) says:

> The United Nations defines ***youth*** as persons ***between the ages
> of 15 and 24*** with all UN statistics based on this range, the UN
> states education as a source for these statistics. The UN also
> recognizes that *this varies without prejudice to other age groups*
> listed by member states such as ***18–30***. A useful distinction
> within the UN itself can be made between *teenagers* (i.e. those
> between the ages of 13 and 19) and ***young adults*** (those
> ***between the ages of 20 and 29***). While seeking to impose some uniformity on statistical approaches, the UN itself is aware of
> *contradictions between approaches in its own statutes*. Hence under the 15–24 definition (introduced in 1981) children are defined as
> those under the age of 14 while under the 1979 Convention on the
> Rights of the Child, those under the age of 18 are regarded as
> children. The UN also states they are aware that several definitions
> exist for ***youth*** within UN entities such as Youth Habitat
> ***15–32*** and *African Youth Charter* ***15–35***.
>
> On November 11, 2020, the State Duma of the Russian Federation
> approved a project to ***raise the cap on the age of young people from
> 30 to 35 years*** (the range now extending from 14 to 35 years).

Comment: Indeed, a middle-aged can be the term I'm looking for ! That's a shame that there is no dedicated term like I said "medior" or something. Maybe by looking at the etymology, we could find out something that can approximate that, I'm really not an expert though. 
Thank you for your answer !